# Dual Boot on XPS 15

Tags: dual-boot, dell, xps

I am considering purchasing a Dell XPS 15 (http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-15-l521x/pd?oc=dncwx16bw7&model_id=xps-15-l521x)

```
Intel® Core™ i7-3632QM processor 
NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 640M with 2GB GDDR5 VRAM
750GB 7200 rpm SATA Hard Drive + 32GB mSATA Solid State Drive
```

I plan on dual booting windows and ubuntu. I'd like to keep windows around to play some games on the laptop, but I plan on primarily using Ubuntu as my workstation.

What is the easiest way to setup a dual boot for this setup?
 Do I have to worry about UEFI e.g. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)? 
Which Ubuntu should I install? 
What other problems should I look out for?

Links to guides would be appreciated!

edit: looks like the 32gb mSATA SDD is used as a cache device for the most frequently accessed data for faster access using the Intel Smart Response Technology. Is Ubuntu able to take advantage of this system?

Similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/459578/ubuntu-on-an-xps-14-ultrabook-with-msata-cache-and-500gb-hd-how-to-partition-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to turn off Intel Smart Response (switch to AHCI), to even get it to boot from dvd on one of these machines.

You need to turn off "[Rapid start](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/what-is-intel-rapid-start-technology)" technology or suspend will resume automatically in Ubuntu, and use up the battery.

Installation is mostly like any other computer, it runs 13.10 just fine. You can manually make a system partition on the SSD, and a home directory on the hard drive during the setup.

See also: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/L521X#preview

It looks like the only no-go is the Bluetooth, at least in Kernel 3.11 until the drivers improve.

***Update -*** I have since updated to 14.04 and bluetooth and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Some more links. Not just precision model as XPS is similar.

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2013/11/14/ubuntu-on-the-precision-m3800.aspx

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Some that are mainly Windows users turn the Intel SRT back on after install. Others that use Ubuntu more leave SRT off and install / (root) into the SSD and all data or /home partitions on the hard drive. With the larger SSD, it may only be using part for the SRT and you can still have / on the SSD.